# wp AJAX load more plugin repeating the same previous posts

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, load

I using wp ajax load more [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) While clicking the button it repeating the same previous post. How to fix it. Here I share my code in below:

```
<?php
       $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'posts_per_page'=>10,//on loading page i show 10 after click load more i want to show other posts
       'post_type'=>'post-name',
       'category_name' => 'A-E',
       'orderby'=> 'title',
       'order'   => 'ASC',
       'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
      ); 
?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

// here I print the following data

 <?php
      endwhile;
 ?>

 <?php
      echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post_type="post-name" posts_per_page="10" category="a-e" button_label="Load More"]');
  ?>
```

can anyone fix it?

Comment: You are not informing the plugin that you have already printed 10 posts :)

Comment: Are you missing some shortcode parameter maybe? Here: [ajax_load_more post_type="post-name" posts_per_page="10" category="a-e" button_label="Load More"], i guess you need to pass also the "paged" parameter, that´s why you are not loading the next page, just always page One. Right?

Comment: Post your shortcode code please. This is where the issues you are having are based.

Comment: see my question i added shortcode in below @designtocode

Comment: I'm asking for php code that makes `[ajax_load_more]`. Have you added this into your functions.php file or is it another plugin?

Comment: its a wp plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the next set of pages with `ajax-load-more` you must use the offset parameter. The `ajax-load-more` plugin must get the next posts that WP_Query has. So both WP_Query and `ajax-load-more` must query the same pages. First alter the shortcode to be same as WP_Query, by adding `order` and `orderby` parameter:

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="post-name" posts_per_page="10" order="ASC" orderby="title" category="a-e" button_label="Load More"]
```

Then add `offset=(get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)*10` like this:

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="post-name" offset='.((get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)*10).' posts_per_page="10" order="ASC" orderby="title"  category="a-e" button_label="Load More"]
```

Note: Seems like `ajax-load-more` doesn't know of `-` so you must separate `category` or `post_type` by `,`. Unless you have actually a category named a-e

Comment: its working. I used another way to add `post__not_in`

Answer (score 1):

I just use this to solve my own problem:

```
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

 $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; // Store post ID in array
  // Other loop actions could go here

 endwhile; wp_reset_query();  

 $post__not_in = ($do_not_duplicate) ? implode(',', $do_not_duplicate) : '';     
 echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more post__not_in="'. $post__not_in .'" post_type="post-name" posts_per_page="10" category="a-e" button_label="Load More"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a custom query. You are using a plugin that will generate it for you via their shortcode. As per their documentation, you can just create your settings for the shortcode.

See instructions here https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/docs/shortcode-builder/

Just take the generated shortcode and paste it into your page/post or in your php file with `do_shortcode`.

The plugin handles the query and the posts per page etc.